# Map field value in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have such class-array:

```
@types = Type.where("TYP_MOD_ID = ?", params[:mod_id])
```

There are i have field TYP_KV_FUEL_DES_ID which is number....
But how can i via map method change this value via method?
I have tried something like:

```
def get_types_for_mod2
    @types = Type.where("TYP_MOD_ID = ?", params[:mod_id])
    @types.map { |e| e.TYP_KV_FUEL_DES_ID = get_via_designation(e.TYP_KV_FUEL_DES_ID) }
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render :json => @types}
    end
  end
def get_via_designation(id)
    designation = Designation.find_by_DES_ID(id)
    destext = DesText.find_by_TEX_ID(designation.DES_TEX_ID)
    destext.TEX_TEXT
  end
```

So how can i change value of e.TYP_KV_FUEL_DES_ID ?

**upd1:**
i don't need to commit anything! just for json i fetch data and change for view some field! no db!

Comment: Seems that you want to use `each` here, instead of `map`.

Comment: `map` returns a transformed array where `each` simply iterates, useful for in-place changes like here.\

Comment: @SergioTulentsev  with each is not good too.....    Write example please

Comment: @tadman and how to solve it?

Comment: why not just use inject? like: `@types.inject([]){|types,el| el.attr = new_attr; types << el}`

Comment: @YevgeniyAnfilofyev and how t ocode this for my environment?

Comment: `@types.inject([]){ |s,e| e.TYP_KV_FUEL_DES_ID = get_via_designation(e.TYP_KV_FUEL_DES_ID); s << e }`

Comment: @YevgeniyAnfilofyev  didn't work.... also note that TYP_KV_FUEL_DES_ID is int.... maybe create new virt,field in array? but how?

Comment: oh, sorry, just figured this out. sure, and you can move all this get_via_designation stuff there. or just keep it as it is...

Comment: @YevgeniyAnfilofyev   this is long-story.... maybe are better ways?

Comment: @ValdisAzamaris have you found a solution yet? I have one in mind but I won't post it if you solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

```
@types = Type.where("TYP_MOD_ID = ?", params[:mod_id]).map do |type| 
  type.TYP_KV_FUEL_DES_ID = get_via_designation(type.TYP_KV_FUEL_DES_ID)
  type
end
```

here we will map over the result from the query `Type.where("TYP_MOD_ID = ?", params[:mod_id])` and set the `TYP_KV_FUEL_DES_ID` to the return from `get_via_designation`

UPDATE: added that the map block will return "type"

Comment: Yeaah... Are you sure about what it will map to?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev updated where it wouldn't just return the new 'TYP_KV_FUEL_DES_ID'. thanks.

Comment: @ValidsAzaramis - have you looked over this answer?